# IIS 7.5 Express + PHP echo shorthand

Tags: php, iis, web, webmatrix, shorthand

i'm a PHP developer, and trying Webmatrix lately,
I have successfully install PHP to IIS, and use it, it's pretty neat I say
then, one time i hit this problem
while

```
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

or

```
<? echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

works just fine,
but

```
<?= "Hello World"; ?>
```

is not working at all, and i thought it was my mistake, then i start apache, and run it from there, and it works..

So, how to get to work?
It work on apache, but not on IIS.. anyone having same problem?

I'm using PHP 5.3.8 + IIS 7.5 Express + Web Matrix

Thanks

---

**Resolved**

OK, I have resolve this problem,
The answer is simple and annoying, I'm using Windows 7, the main problem is UAC,
every time i save the php.ini, it's saved to the Virtual Store instead of the original location (because i dont use administrator right when editing)
I tried to edit the php.ini under administrator right, and Boom! worked like a charm!

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Do you get an error or does it display blank or does it just show up as plain text?

Comment: everything works fine, except that every text that i print using <?= (shorthand) does not show up..

Answer (score 1):

Check if the short-open-tag is enabled in your php.ini

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Yep, check it and it's enable so i can use <? ?> instead <?php ?>
Thanks for answering

Comment: 5.3.8, uh.. could you tell me how to "reload" the php.ini? i think it have something to do with that, i have  try to change some other configuration insied php.ini and restart the computer, but it seems the php is not even affected..

Comment: Weird, that should have solved this... Try restart your WebMatrix. Also, check your `Loaded Configuration File` with `phpinfo()` if you are editing the right `php.ini`.

Comment: I have use phpinfo(), and it show right the file I edit.. Because my apache and IIS use the same php, is there any side effect on that? Thanks again, i'll try to figure this out.. and if i cant, i'll just return to apache :)